# Can not config elastic search to ignore hyphen in word split

Tags: elasticsearch

I got an identifier that contains hyphen, here got an example **023-019125**.
When I use elastic search to search this identifier it splits in the next two words **023** and **019125**

I need to search by the exact value of this field. I'm using an old elastic search version (5.2.1) and can not update it. I need to know how can I configure fos_elastica.yaml for that purpose.

In this configuration I got another fields that must keep a partial search with hyphen split word.

Comment: Are you using elasticsearch or other similar product ? What is fos_elastica.yaml  ? And what's your mapping ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I take an old company product to improve it. They told me that elastic search was failing when they try to search by a service identifier. When I tried, I saw the problem is a hyphen in the identifier. I only know right now the elastic search version and it's configuration. **fos_elsatica.yaml** is elastic search configuration file for this project.